# Variables in href

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to add a variable in an href so that it looks like, or behaves like, this:

```
var user = "YourName";
$("#main-container .profile-link[href='/home/user/' + player + '/']")
```

I'm hoping to be able to select all the users that I have in that variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use proper string enclosures

```
$('#main-container .profile-link[href="/home/user/' + player + '/"]')
```

In your case since the string literal is started using `"` you need to use the same to close the string before the variable is concatenated like  `"#main-container .profile-link[href='/home/user/" + player + "/']"`